# Cannot compile .msi project in MFC application in visual studio 2008. Expect conflict between english and Japanese version of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I am trying to compile a massive C++ MFC application.  It compiles perfectly in the Japanese version of VS 2008 Professional on a different PC.  When I try to compile it on a PC with the English version of VS 2008 Professional, all of the projects in the solution compile no problem. The problem comes when trying to install the .msi (setup) project.  I am not very familiar with MFC applications, but I am pretty experienced (informally) with programming.  I hope someone has an idea for this.  It seems to be related to VS rather than a programming problem.

I get these warnings that seem to predicate the build errors for the shortcuts for the projects:

WARNING: Could not match culture 'ja-JP' for item 'Visual C++ Runtime LIbraries (x86)'. Using culture 'en' instead

WARNING: Could not match culture 'ja-JP' for item 'Windows Installer 3.1'. Using culture 'en' instead

I have tried downloading and installing the Japanese Runtime Libraries and Windows Installer 3.1 but I still get these warnings

The PC is running Windows 7 Ultimate with English and Japanese language packs installed.  Is there some way to correct these warnings?